# Latin numbers (such as "xxv," "xxxv," "iii," and "ii") in R

Tags: r, text, numbers, data-cleaning, latin

How to convert all the Latin numbers (such as "xxv," "xxxv," "iii," and "ii") into numerical values in text data with R?

I need to convert all the Latin numbers in a text data into numerical values. Is there any function in R can convert all the Latin numbers at once?

In addition, when I replace one by one, what if I have some words contains letters like "ii", "i"?  For example, would the world "still" be changed into "st1ll"?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The OP wants to substitute the latin numbers ***in a text***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt <- 'How to convert all the Latin numbers (such as "xxv," "xxxv," "iii," and "ii") into numerical values in text data with R?
  
I need to convert all the Latin numbers in a text data into numerical values. Is there any function in R can convert all the Latin numbers at once?
  
In addition, when I replace one by one, what if I have some words contains letters like "ii", "i"? For example, would the world "still" be changed into "st1ll"?'
```

Get a vector of roman characters (note if you make this too large, the `gregexpr` will throw an error, I didn't test to see what the limit is, however--it's somewhere between 1e2 and 1e3)

Exclude "I" since that is more likely not to be a numeral, then create your pattern and treat it like any other string find/replace:

```
rom <- as.character(as.roman(1:1e2))
rom <- setdiff(rom, 'I')

p <- sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', paste0(na.omit(rom), collapse = '|'))
m <- gregexpr(p, txt, ignore.case = TRUE)
regmatches(txt, m) <- lapply(regmatches(txt, m), function(x) as.numeric(as.roman(x)))

cat(txt)

# How to convert all the Latin numbers (such as "25," "35," "3," and "2") into numerical values in text data with R?
#   
# I need to convert all the Latin numbers in a text data into numerical values. Is there any function in R can convert all the Latin numbers at once?
#   
# In addition, when I replace one by one, what if I have some words contains letters like "2", "i"? For example, would the world "still" be changed into "st1ll"?
```

As a function:

```r
dd <- data.frame(
  texts = rep(txt, 5)
)

rom_to_num <- function(text, rom = 1:1e2, exclude = 'I') {
  rom <- as.character(as.roman(rom))
  rom <- setdiff(rom, exclude)
  
  p <- sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', paste0(na.omit(rom), collapse = '|'))
  m <- gregexpr(p, text, ignore.case = TRUE)
  regmatches(text, m) <- lapply(regmatches(text, m), function(x) as.numeric(as.roman(x)))
  
  text
}

dd <- within(dd, {
  texts_new <- rom_to_num(texts)
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert only the independent Latin number(I mean with space ahead and following)? I do not want "ii" and "iv" to disappear in other words in the text.

Comment: See the answer to your other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74399312/how-to-select-the-number-in-a-text-r/74400995#74400995

Comment: @Emily they dont, there are even instances of those not changing in your example

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Answer accepted! I just have one more follow-up question: My data structure is a data frame, and I have text as a variable for over 1000 observations. I followed your code, and it worked well to convert numbers. But the text from each observation converges into a whole and does not correspond to the observation one by one. How can I solve this problem? I am a beginner with R, and thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Emily you just need to apply the code as a loop or create a function, see edits